# Node.js server printing static dates that are hours behind actual value

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone

Trying to print a time from my node application on a heroku server. The times printing out aren't matching up...

It's a 6 hour difference (we're in GMT-6) so it would make sense that it's a timezome issue. However, I'm conflicted because the dates printed are created in the format:

```
var time = (new Date('2012', '12', '10')).valueOf();
console.log(time);
```

Gives `1355097600000` instead of `1355119200000`.

Staticly created dates should always be static right? No matter what timezone you're in, the beginning of `2012/12/10` should be the same length from `1970/01/01`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript creates dates based on the time zone of the browser or node server. To get a static date, you need to pass in the timezone you want the date created in. Examples:

```
var time = (new Date('December, 2012 12:00:00 pm GMT')).valueOf(); 
console.log(time)
```

returns

```
1354363200000
```

My timezone is PST, so if I do

```
var time = (new Date('December, 2012 12:00:00 pm PST')).valueOf(); 
console.log(time)
```

It returns the same value (1354392000000) as if I'd done

```
var time = (new Date('December, 2012 12:00:00 pm')).valueOf(); 
console.log(time)
```